# Does Feynman parametrization commute with derivative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Let $I = \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{(p+k)\cdot\gamma}{(p+k)^2-m^2+i\epsilon} \frac{1}{k^2+i\epsilon}$

I would like to do two operations on the integral, namely Feynman parametrization and $\frac{\partial}{\partial p\cdot \gamma}$. Of course, Feynman parametrization is just a re-expression of the integrand, thus there seems to be no reason for order of these operations to be important. However, I seem to get different answers.

If I do the Feynman parametrization first, shift integral variable, then take the derivative, 
I get
$$ \sim\frac{i}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\frac{1}{\Delta^{2-\frac{d}{2}}}\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})\int_0^1dx [(1-x)+\frac{2}{\Delta}(2-\frac{d}{2})p^2x(1-x)^2]$$

and if I take the derivative first, do feynman parametrization, then shift integral variable, I get
$$ \sim\frac{i}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\frac{1}{\Delta^{2-\frac{d}{2}}}\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})\int_0^1dx [(1-dx)+\frac{2}{\Delta}(2-\frac{d}{2})p^2x(1-x)^2]$$ which are clearly not the same.

$\Delta = xm^2-xp^2(1-x)$.

Comment: So turns out, the problem is not whether you take the derivative or feynman parametrization first, but whether you shift integral before you take the derivative or not.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839671/shifting-integration-variable-and-taking-derivative-seemingly-giving-problem